# Splitting a comma-seperated string in a v-for method

Tags: javascript, html, vuejs2

I'm trying to split a string on each comma using a `v-for` method from Vue.js.

**Input:**  `tags: 'test1, test2, test3'`
**Method:** `<span v-for="tag in tags" v-text="tag"/>`
**Output:** `t e s t 1 , t e s t 2 , t e s t 3`
**Desired output:** `test1 test2 test3`

How could I split the comma-separated text correctly? I cannot access 'tags' input unless I am in a `v-for` loop in order to call `object.tags`.

Not sure why this does not work although It's pretty much the same thing in my code: https://jsfiddle.net/9o3o11jc/1/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `String.prototype.split()` to turn your string into an array of words.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {objects:[{tags: 'test1, test2, test3'}]}
   },
   methods: {
      splitJoin(theText){
       return theText.split(', ');
      }
   } 
});
```

```html
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.9/vue.min.js'></script>
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="object in objects">
    <span v-for="tag in splitJoin(object.tags)" v-text="tag"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I never thought I could use methods like this! Wow! Thank you very much.

Comment: @GordonFreemanTurtle You're welcome.  You can also do the split directly on the object in the v-for like `tag in object.tags.split(', ')`.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want the [split](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) method from javascript and the seperator ", ". The v-for directive is reading the string as a collection of characters, because object.tags is a single string. What you want is a collection of strings, which is what split will return.